# Limiting Excel Columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am creating an order form which the customer can purchase the product and select only 2 delivery dates out of 5 dates. Therefore I would like once they have typed the order into 2 columns that the remaining options are blocked out (Not able to type in those columns)

For Example Below This Shop has selected to order in June & August, therefore, i want the document to lock out all other months (July, September, October)

Is there a way to complete this in excel, Thank-you in advance.
[image]

Comment: The best possible method to do so in apply VBA code since you want to lock any 3 Columns if other 2 have been populated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Data Validation** for each row in the Table.

You can enter the formula with **Costum** option:

Apple Row C4:G4: `=COUNTIF($C$4:$G$4,"<>")<3`

Banana Row C5:G5: `=COUNTIF($C$5:$G$5,"<>")<3`

Grapefruit Row C6:G6: `=COUNTIF($C$6:$G$6,"<>")<3`

Mango Row C7:G7: `=COUNTIF($C$7:$G$7,"<>")<3`

Passionfruit Row C8:G8: `=COUNTIF($C$8:$G$8,"<>")<3`

[image]

Comment: It appears @brooke wants to constrain months altogether, not individually. Consider applying the Data Validation Formula `=SUM((COUNT($C$5:$C$9)>0),(COUNT($D$5:$D$9)>0),(COUNT($E$5:$E$9)>0),(COUNT($F$5:$F$9)>0),(COUNT($G$5:$G$9)>0))<3` to the entire range.

Comment: @Lee, what the OP want is, if  either of the 2 Columns has been populated with data then rest 3 Columns should not  accept even a single Value!! Your example shows data in all Columns ??